# htaccess - rewrite multiple directories to query strings on all urls

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to find a catch-all solution to redirect every URL to the root file (index.php) with all the directories passed as query strings.

For example;

```
mywebsite.co.uk/one  =>  mywebsite.co.uk?p1=one
mywebsite.co.uk/one/two  =>  mywebsite.co.uk?p1=one&p2=two
mywebsite.co.uk/one/two/three  =>  mywebsite.co.uk?p1=one&p2=two&p3=three
```

I only seem to be able to put together rules that work *if* I know the number of directories/query strings.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think regexes, as implemented by mod_rewrite, are powerful enough for this. The usual approach is to pass the whole path as one query string parameter, and process it further in the application code.

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess

Comment: Does this help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69515573/combine-several-rewriterule-directives-into-a-single-rule-in-htaccess

Comment: Presumably there is an upper limit to the number of path segments (directories)?